# Android DB Update registers

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

ok...I'm pretty stuck on this thing.
I've searched a lot, even here in stackoverflow but I got nothing to solve my problem.
The thing is: I'm trying to update a single column in my DB, but it always get an error and it doesn't work, and I'm not even close to know what the problem is.

I've try to use the SQLiteDatabase.update() , doesn't work , and now with the execSQL(String); same error.

So I'm going to show my codes and please, if someone has some idea what's the problem is...please help me.

```
public void AbreouCriaBD() {
    try {
        String nomeBanco = "Usuarios";
        dataBase = openOrCreateDatabase(nomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario" + 
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT, senha TEXT, saldoBanco float, saldoCredito float, saldoFuturos float)";
            dataBase.execSQL(sql);
    } catch(Exception erro) {
        Alerta("Erro BD","BD Não criado");
    }
}

public void UpdateBDPrincipal(double saldo) {
    String saldoString = String.valueOf(saldo);
    try {
        dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE usuario SET 'saldoBanco'="+ saldoString +"WHERE 'login'= cristiano");
    } catch(Exception error) {
        Alerta("Erro","Erro no UPDATE");
    }
}

public void Alerta(String title,String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder Sucesso = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelaSaldoCredito.this);
    Sucesso.setTitle(title);
    Sucesso.setMessage(message);
    Sucesso.setNeutralButton("ok", null);
    Sucesso.show();
}
```

It just doesn't work...please anything...

```
08-16 15:36:24.729: W/System.err(10855): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at com.bunchoffat.financejournal.TelaSaldoCredito.UpdateBDPrincipal(TelaSaldoCredito.java:121)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at com.bunchoffat.financejournal.TelaSaldoCredito$1.onClick(TelaSaldoCredito.java:62)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2579)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9246)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 15:36:24.739: W/System.err(10855): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-16 15:36:24.759: W/System.err(10855): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
08-16 15:36:24.759: W/System.err(10855): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
08-16 15:36:24.759: W/System.err(10855): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

as I can see the error is NullPointerException ... but...I don't know why...there is data on the dataBase, I'm prety sure of that, cause I can login in the system, and the password is on the dataBase...so..what am I missing here?

Comment: try like this db.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

Comment: I've try this one too, but it doesn't work either.
   this one is tricky. In the ContentValues I've must put the key the same name as the column name, right? And in the whereClause just "'login' = cristiano" right? Did it, and same error...

Comment: We could also need more information. Do you use the Android provider pattern (i.e. are you extending from `ContentProvider`)? Are you also using `SQLiteOpenHelper` which helps to abstract the SQLite making updates and upgrades easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your query. After you add the saldoString you do not have a space before the WHERE statement.

```
public void UpdateBDPrincipal(double saldo){

    String saldoString = String.valueOf(saldo);
    try{
        dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE usuario SET 'saldoBanco'="+ saldoString +" WHERE 'login'= cristiano");
    } catch(Exception error) {
        Alerta("Erro","Erro no UPDATE");
    }
}
```

P.S. be careful when building SQL strings this way, it can be vulnerable for SQL injection attacks. In this specific case it "works", because saldo is a double. But if it would be a string it's very dangerous to create strings without escaping or putting strings in `''`

**Update:**
Also please do not suppress your exception output, this makes tracking errors much harder.

```
    try {
    } catch(Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace(); // Print error to the log
        Alerta("Erro","Erro no UPDATE");
    }
```

and then use logcat to read the Android log. If you are using Eclipse for debugging the Logcat is a one of the windows added. If you don't use or test it with eclipse run "adb logcat" in your command line (your Smartphone has to be connected to your computer via USB).

**Update 2:**
Here is an example on how to use SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class MyServiceProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "usuario";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // Initialize the database and assign it to the private variable
        MyDatabaseHelper sqlHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        return (db == null)?false:true;
    }

    public void UpdateBDPrincipal(double saldo){

        String saldoString = String.valueOf(saldo);
        try {
            dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE usuario SET 'saldoBanco'="+ saldoString +"WHERE 'login'= cristiano");
        } catch(Exception error) {
            Alerta("Erro","Erro no UPDATE");
        }
    }
}

class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyAppTag";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Usuarios";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "usuario";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario" + 
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT, senha TEXT, saldoBanco float, saldoCredito float, saldoFuturos float)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Here you can perform updates when the database structure changes
        // Begin transaction
        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            if(oldVersion<2){
                // Upgrade database structure from Version 1 to 2
                String alterTable = "ALTER ....";

                db.execSQL(alterTable);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Successfully upgraded to Version 2");
            }

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Ends transaction
            // If there was an error, the database won't be altered
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you have a clear abstraction between Database creation and loading and the way the queries are built or processed (i.e. by overriding the update, delete, query methods).

**Edit:** 
Usage of `SQLiteDatabase.update()`:

```
private String userName = "cristiano";

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("saldoBanco", 150.23);

// define the WHERE clause but do not directly concat values into the string
// Use question marks (?) as place holders. 
String whereClause = "WHERE login = ?";

// define a list of args. For each '?' used in WHERE clause, add one element to the array
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { userName };

int numRowsUpdated = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

When executed, the question marks will be replaced with the elements from `whereArgs`. First question mark will be replaced by first element of `whereArgs`, second question mark will be replaced by the second `whereArgs` etc.

This way you can easily create where clauses and avoiding to risk a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: I've put the space before where...and still showing the error...
anything else?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error? Like adding a logcat output in your opening post? You have posted code but no error, it is hard to guess what it may cause it. Error messages are important to get the reason why it's happening.

Comment: Also you are suppressing the real exception in your code. You should add `error.printStackTrace()` in your error handling, so that the error message is printed to the logcat window instead of being suppressed.

Comment: Thanks. The only position on where the `NullPointerException` can occur is in `dataBase.execSQL` where `dataBase` is null. 

Do you load the Database? Can you post the constructor of your class? I see only `public void AbreouCriaBD()` but not where it is called. It is likely that you do not read the database in the constructor which cause `dataBase` to be `null`.

Comment: Good Lord...Tseng ...thanks a lot...I must be the dummiest ever...I forgot to use the AbreOuCriaBD() in first place...but I've stuck in another issue...the data isn't updating...thanks a lot man!

Comment: The logcat was the important indication. In future always add the error messages you get as specific as possible. And consider to mark the question as accepted, so the answer won't appear in "Unanswered Questions" anymore.

Comment: using the SQLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,ContentValues cv, null, null); worked! But it only works for me cause I have only one row in this dataBase. the whereClause still a mistery to me.